# gVim: Once in command-line mode, how can I paste a selection?

Tags: gvim

In gVim, once in command-line mode (typed ':'), how can I paste a selection made with the mouse after entering command-line mode, into the command-line?

For instance, I start typing  :g//s//_

Then, I use my mouse to make a selection in the text, but I fail to find any means to paste the selection at my cursor's position (represented in the above command as an underscore).  I notice that the color of the selection is not the same as when I am out of the command-line mode, suggesting that my selection is in some special mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you copied by dragging the mouse, then you can paste by right clicking while in command line mode.

If you copied by `y` commands (like yy, y$, yaw) then by default those content will be in register `"`. While you are in command line,  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and then a `"`. It will paste the recently copied text through yanks.